# C++ OpenMP working really slow on matrix-vector product

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

So, I'm making matrix-vector product using openMP, but I've noticed it's working reallllly slow. After some times trying to figure out whats wrong I just deleted all code in parallel section and its still SLOW. What can be problem here? (n = 1000)

Here is time results for 1, 2 and 4 cores.

> seq_method time = 0.001047194215062
>
> parrallel_method (1) time = 0.001050273191140 seq - par =
>   -0.000003078976079 seq/par = 0.997068404578433
>
> parrallel_method (2) time = 0.001961992426004 seq - par =
>   -0.000914798210943 seq/par = 0.533740192460558
>
> parrallel_method (4) time = 0.004448095121916 seq - par =
>   -0.003400900906854 seq/par = 0.235425319459132

Even when I delete code from parallel section - it doesnt change much.

```
void parallel_method(float A[n][n], float B[n], float C[n], int thr_num)
{
    double t1, t2;
    float tmp = 0;
    int i, j;
    t1 = omp_get_wtime();


    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(thr_num);
#pragma omp parallel for private(tmp, j, i)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            tmp += A[i][j] * B[j];
        }
#pragma omp atomic
        C[i] += tmp;
    }

    //////
    t2 = omp_get_wtime();
    if (show_c) print_vector(C);
    par = t2 - t1;
    printf("\nparrallel_method (%d) time = %.15f", thr_num, par);
    printf("\nseq - par = %.15f", seq - par);
    printf("\nseq/par = %.15f\n", seq / par);
}
```

Code:
https://pastebin.com/Q20t5DLk

Comment: How are you building the code? Are compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: x64 release, with /O2 favor Speed.
(All of it on core i5-3330)

Comment: Your problem size is almost trivial, and your code contains the lead weight of an atomic update.  Do at least two things: try the code on much larger problem sizes (ones which take perhaps 10s for the sequential version of the code) and, with a bit more effort, replace your `atomic` with an OpenMP `reduction`.

Comment: Did it, still slow performance on N<5000, while Alain Merigot is having normal behavior. (Completely removed atomic, because iterator is private)

Comment: "I'm making matrix-vector product using openMP". Why? You can see it;'s not trivial, and many people have spent a lot of time writing heavily optimised versions of routines in this class. Use  a BLAS routine (spmv?). Good ones will be parallelised and cache-blocked and outperform yours. I know reading a manual is more painful than writing code, but... (FWIW Intel MKL is available for free to everyone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and was not able to do that. 
I have a completely coherent behavior.

```
n=100
sequential_method (0) time = 0.000023339001928
parallel_method (1) time = 0.000023508997401
parallel_method (2) time = 0.000013864002540
parallel_method (4) time = 0.000008979986887

n=1000
sequential_method (0) time = 0.001439775005565
parallel_method (1) time = 0.001437967992388
parallel_method (2) time = 0.000701391996699
parallel_method (4) time = 0.000372130998080

n=10000
sequential_method (0) time = 0.140988592000213
parallel_method (1) time = 0.133375317003811
parallel_method (2) time = 0.077803490007180
parallel_method (4) time = 0.044142695999355
```

Except for small size, where thread overhead is significant, the results are more or less what is expected.

What I did:

- all measures are done in the same run
- I run all functions once without timing to warm-up the caches

In real code estimations, I would have also

- time several successive executions of the same function, especially if time is short in order to reduce small variations
- run several experiments and keep the smallest one to suppress outliers. (I prefer minimum, but you can also compute the average).

You should have posted all you code, and I do not know what is your methodology. But I think that your estimations where done in different runs and without warming up the caches. For this code, cache impact is very important and cores have to store the same information (B). And the problem is not large enough to benefit from the larger L1/L2 caches. These multiples loads may explain the worse performances of parallel code.

On last remark on your code. Every thread will have their own values of i. Hence C[i] can be accessed by only one thread and the atomic pragma is useless.

Comment: It's strange, that we are having different results on same code. I get small decrease in parallel time only for N> ~5000, for less N (for ex. 1000) I get significant increase, like :
seq_method time = 0.003223346579034
Parallel_method (1 c) time = 0.003273294423707
Parallel_method (2 c) time = 0.004890441454336
Parallel_method (4 c) time = 0.006931803061889

Comment: Are you *certain* to warm up the caches with a blank execution before doing your measurements? This is what I do, and it is required if you want to measure core performances. On the contrary, if I blank the caches between every measure, I have times that are largely dispersed and time with 4 cores can be larger than times with a smaller parallelism.

Comment: Can u explain more about this, please? I dont fully understand, what I have to do to "warm up caches".

Comment: Just run your function once without timing it to fill the caches. And then perform your real measure. Otherwise you measure the time to fetch data from memory to the caches (that does not scale with #cores)  + code execution time.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Can u say, where can I read about this, to fully understand (Or keywords)? And last silly question - I shound just run a parallel funtion on 4 cores and then all program, or should I run a function without time measurment, and then same function, but with time measurment, I got it right? Thanks for all of this, again.

Comment: There are many good tutorials on caches. Try wikipedia or search in SO. Caches are small memory associated to cores that memorize recent data read or written. Run and time your function twice and you will see the difference when caches are empty or already filled by previous execution. And keep the second timing to evaluate multicore acceleration.