# increasing thread numbers on xcode increases program time

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm new to openmp and currently am trying to paralleling matrix multiplication in xcode on mac.

The result i'm getting is weird because it increases my program time instead of lowering it. my guess is that it's happening because it is using only one core and not using other cores here is my code :

```
omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k)
for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
               for (k=0; k<n; ++k) {
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
               }
        } 
}
```

on two 400*400 matrixes with 1 thread i get a 551 ms, with 2 threads 421 and with 3 threads 678 and it increases as i increase my threads.

any ideas what am i doing wrong or what should i do?!

Comment: Synchronization probably

Comment: There's diminishing and eventually negative returns for excessive parallelization. Find the sweet spot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ OpenMP working really slow on matrix-vector product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958186/c-openmp-working-really-slow-on-matrix-vector-product)

Comment: You don't seem to be distinguishing clearly between threads and cores.  How many (physical) cores does your machine actually provide?  It is unlikely to be helpful to use more threads than you have cores to run them on.

Comment: my laptop has 4 cores but more than two threads starts to increase the time rather to lowering it @JohnBollinger

Comment: tried to warm up caches as it says in the topic u mentioned but seems like it's not the case for me @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: How are you timing this?

Comment: And did you experiment with much larger problem sizes ?  Also, don't expect hyperthreads sharing a single core to magically give the same kind of performance as multiple cores.  Generally, for many HPC workloads such as matrix multiplication, hyperthreads provide no benefit, often a slow down as ou seem to have observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a *bad* method to multiply your matrices. The ijk algorithm generates many cache misses. Look at you inner loop. Whenever your index k changes, you go to a new lines of matrix `b` instead of using a cache friendly traversal along a row. And this large number of cache misses reduces your performances and is nastier for parallel code because of cache coherency algorithms. The ikj algorithm (see code below) is much better. Matrices are all traversed row major and do not generate cache misses.

I tried to experiment with your code.

To have a steady timing, I time 10 loops of matrix multiplication, and I do that 10 times and I keep the lowest time.

Depending of defines, one can choose either ijk  or ikj and control the parallelism.

Another define select parallel or sequential version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    double a[400][400], b[400][400], c[400][400] = { { 0.0 } };
    int i, j, k, n = 400;

    double t1, t2,t;

    srand(100); // better be deterministic when benchmarking
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
            b[i][j] = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
        }
    }

    t=1E100;
    for(int ll=0;ll<10;ll++){      
      t1 = omp_get_wtime();
      for(int mm=0;mm<10;mm++){
#if THREADS>1
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k) num_threads(THREADS)
#endif
#ifdef ijk
        for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
          for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
            for (k=0; k<n; ++k) {
              c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
          } 
        }
#else // ikj matrix multiplication
        for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
          for (k=0; k<n; ++k) {
            double r=a[i][k];
            for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
              c[i][j] += r * b[k][j];
            }
          } 
        }
#endif      
      }
      t2 = omp_get_wtime();
      if (t>t2-t1) t=t2-t1;
    }

    printf("%g\n",t);

    // to fool these smart optimizers, do something with c
    FILE* devnull=fopen("/dev/null","w");
    fprintf(devnull,"%g\n",c[0][0]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now the experiments:

First with ijk

```
am@Mandel$ cc -fopenmp -O3 -march=native -DTHREADS=0 -Dijk omp2.c; ./a.out
0.196313
am@Mandel$ cc -fopenmp -O3 -march=native -DTHREADS=4 -Dijk omp2.c; ./a.out
0.293023
```

And we see that the parallel version is ~50% slower.

Now we switch to ikj

```
am@Mandel$ cc -fopenmp -O3 -march=native -DTHREADS=0 -Uijk omp2.c; ./a.out
0.114659
am@Mandel$ cc -fopenmp -O3 -march=native -DTHREADS=4 -Uijk omp2.c; ./a.out
0.06113
```

Now the sequential code is ~twice faster and the parallel version is ~twice faster than the sequential one.

Probably with larger matrices you can improve efficiency of parallel code.

Comment: sound like this solved my problem thanks. also i used to calculate time using clock_t tStart = clock() function but it seems omp_get_wtime() gives better and more accurate answer any ideas why?

Comment: Excellent answer. (Minor observation: If you wanted actual matrix products, e.g. to verify the calculations, you’d obviously want to reinitialize c each iteration, but that’s not really material to the performance question.)

Answer (score 0):

> any ideas what am i doing wrong or what should i do?!

It doesn't look like you're doing anything in particular wrong as far as your code.  Multithreading carries overhead, however, both at the software level and at the hardware level.  As a result, applying more threads to a problem does not always speed the overall computation, and may slow it down.  How that affects a particular task depends on on details of that task and of the host architecture and environment.

Nevertheless, consider this complete test program built around your example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    double a[400][400], b[400][400], c[400][400] = { { 0.0 } };
    int i, j, k, n = 400;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
            b[i][j] = rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,k) num_threads(4)
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
           for (k=0; k<n; ++k) {
               c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
           }
        } 
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am using a `num_threads` clause on the `parallel for` construct instead of calling `omp_set_numThreads()` to set the requested number of threads, but otherwise the OMP region is identical to yours.  Timing this crudely, via the `time` command, on my own Linux system, I see that elapsed time goes down with number of threads, exhibiting near-linear speedup, until about four threads.  After that, there's a slight speedup with a fifth thread, and both elapsed time and aggregate CPU time starts increasing at six threads.

Those results likely correlate with the fact that my machine has six physical CPU cores, and the OS and various background processes consume a certain amount of CPU resources all the time.  That your results do not follow the same pattern may be related to the rest of your program, or to your environment, or to your particular OpenMP implementation.  It may even be related to how you're running your time trials.  It's not because the OpenMP region you've presented is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Your big mistake is trying to parallelize matrix multiplication. Not because it's impossible, but because it has already been done (along with other important optimizations like cache-blocking and vectorization which you likely won't get around to).

Remember the key phrase: "The best code is the code I don't have to write" :-)

So, unless your aim is to educate yourself, stop doing this. Instead find a good BLAS library and spend your time learning how to use it.

([Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl) is good and free to everyone so that's a reasonable choice, but there are many other options which Google can find for you).

Full disclosure: I work for Intel, but not on MKL.

Comment: yea as u said i'm trying to educate myself and this is actually a homework for parallel algorithms which i have but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Ah, OK, so it's not your fault. Next time it'd be worth mentioning that up-front...